# dateFormat always returns nil

Tags: ios, swift2, nsdateformatter

I'm getting a dateFormat from the server like this:

```
2016-09-04T17:44:44+02:00
```

So I wrote a dateformatter:

```
private static let jsonDateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = {
    let fmt = NSDateFormatter()
    fmt.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss+SSS"
    return fmt
}()
```

there is still a problem because when I do `jsonDateFormatter.dateFromString` it returns nil so the dateFormat must be wrong.

I don't see the problem.

Comment: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ`?

Comment: The plus sign belongs to the time zone part, replace `+SSS` with `Z`, `S` stands for fractional seconds which is wrong.

Comment: Thank you Vadian :) that was the problem.

Comment: You've already gotten the correct answer, but I have a suggestion for the future. If you create a date formatter and passing in a string to `dateFromString` returns nil, try calling `stringFromDate` and examining the result. It should help you figure out where your format string doesn't match your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the Documentation given on Apple Docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/index.html)

The correct formatter for this type of Dates will be

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ
```

As it is used in the give example

```
let RFC3339DateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
RFC3339DateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
RFC3339DateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
//RFC3339DateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)

/* 39 minutes and 57 seconds after the 16th hour of December 19th, 1996 with an offset of -08:00 from UTC (Pacific Standard Time) */
let string = "1996-12-19T16:39:57-08:00"
let date = RFC3339DateFormatter.dateFromString(string)
```

Comment: Do not set the formatter's timezone. The date string has a timezone and the timezone should be parsed from the string.

Comment: I agree that setting the time zone is not needed, but at the same time, it does not adversely affect the formatter (it will always use the timezone in the string). And the virtue of setting the `timezone` is that this formatter can also be used for constructing ISO8601/RFC3339 date strings from date objects, and these strings will always be represented in consistent GMT format (which can be useful if you're storing the dates in a SQLite database).

Answer (score 0):

Wrong format string, plus you should also read Apple's [Q&A on parsing internet date](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1480/_index.html):

```
private static let jsonDateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = {
    let fmt = NSDateFormatter()
    fmt.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
    fmt.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    return fmt
}()
```